# Kohana 3.2 модуль auth orm

Tags: php, kohana

Не так работает модуль. При авторизации со значением `$remember = TRUE`, должен отправлять куки на 2 недели с токеном, а токен записывать в базу. А он отправляет куки до закрытия браузера(не чего не записывая в бд) и при `Auth::instance()->logout($destroy = TRUE)` не удаляет куки, хотя должен.

Вот, что в контроллере

```
 $login = Arr::get($_POST, 'login', '');
        $password = Arr::get($_POST, 'password', '');
        $remember = $_POST['remember'];

        $auth->login($login,$password, $remember);
```

Вот конфиг auth.php

```
return array(

'driver'       => 'ORM',
'hash_method'  => 'sha256',
'hash_key'     => '2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 15, 20, 23, 25, 30',
'lifetime'     => 1209600,
'session_type' => Session::$default,
'session_key'  => 'auth_user',
```

Comment: Позавчера авторизацию делал в kohana)
$remember ведь там логическая переменная. 
Сделай
$remember = isset($_POST['remember']);
Вообще вроде всё норм. Должно работать

Comment: неа, не работает

Comment: а remember у тебя ведь на чекбоксе? правильно я понимаю?

Comment: да он на чекбоксе

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил проблему, только таким способом:

```
$auth->login($login,$password, TRUE);
```

По другому не как не получается, при приеме $remember

Comment: `var_dump($remember)` смотрели? Чудес не бывает

Comment: конечно -_-

Comment: @AlexWindHope, НГ на носу. может и бывают =)
@trane294, и что var_dump говорит? true или false? а при передаче его в качестве параметра ничего не работает? Точно сказки)

Comment: при его получении если значение не указать присылает ON, $auth->login($_POST['username'], $password, $_POST['remember']=='ON'?TRUE:FALSE)); не работает. Просто если послать TRUE и вставить то тоже. Много, что перепробовал не работает(

Comment: ладно. Говори что именно не работает тогда? Все равно сейчас с kohana сижу)

Comment: Вот я и не знаю, что не работает, хотя все нужные данные присылаются и вставляются

Comment: В таком случае и я не знаю.
Cookie::$salt установлено?

Answer (score 1):

```
 $status = Auth::instance()->login($data['username'], $data['password'], isset($_POST['remember']) ? true: false);
```

Если в $_POST['remember'] передается значение из чекбокса.

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте.
При проверке вардампом выдаёт 1 или NULL.
Поэтому поставил условие перед логином.

```
        $data = Arr::extract($_POST, array('username', 'password', 'remember'));

        //var_dump($data['remember']); //выдаёт 1 или NULL
        //die();
        // Поэтому поставил условие перед логином.
        if($data['remember'] == 1)
        {
            $flag = TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            $flag = FALSE;
        }
        $status = Auth::instance()->login($data['username'], $data['password'], $flag);
```